# Calling ServiceStack Service from WCF

Tags: wcf, servicestack

I work in a company that is only using WCF and i am trying to introduce service stack. Now i understand we are better off using the service stackclients that wcf clients but for some of our stuff and to keep people happy that will not always be possible. Can anyone provide a basic example of a ServiceStack service that can be added as a client into a VS2012 project using the add service reference inside visual studio as you normally do for a WCF service?  Basically is there a way to make ServiceStack seem like a WCF service to people that don't know about ServiceStack?

If i can show this i think i can convince my company to make the switch but if not it will be difficult as everything else is WCF based. We are already using the ServiceStack clients to hook into other online websites so it seems a good time to try to convince them to move to the service stack services and clients as long as they feel they can fall back to the WCF client if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you adhere to the [SOAP guidelines and limitations in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) you should be able to add a Service Reference by pointing the client to the ServiceStack wsdl at `/soap12`, e.g:

```
http://servicestackbaseurl/soap12
```

You can also find a link to the soap 1.1/1.2 wsdl (and XSDs) on ServiceStack's `/metadata` page.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any samples for this available? I tried once before but must have done something wrong. If not i will give it ago again when i get a chance. Can servicestack work as a WCF client as well?